How to prevent interactions with hidden TabBar area without blocking other UI elements?
The Problem
I have a custom TabBar in SwiftUI that can be shown/hidden with animation. The issue is with handling interactions when the TabBar is hidden:

I need to prevent any interactions in the exact area where the TabBar would be (to prevent accidental taps)
When I block the interactions, it blocks ALL UI elements in that area (like buttons or other interactive elements that should work)
Without blocking, users can still "click" the invisible TabBar buttons

Current Implementation
Here's my complete code:
import SwiftUI

struct MainTabView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab = 0
    @State private var tabBarVisible = true
    @State private var tabBarHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                // Main content
                TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                    HomeView()
                        .tag(0)
                    FavoritesView()
                        .tag(1)
                    EmptyView()
                        .tag(2)
                    SettingsView()
                        .tag(3)
                }
                
                // Custom tab bar
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    Spacer()
                    if tabBarVisible {
                        CustomTabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab, tabbarVisible: $tabBarVisible)
                            .padding(.bottom, geometry.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
                            .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                            .background(
                                GeometryReader { geo in
                                    Color.clear.onAppear {
                                        tabBarHeight = geo.size.height
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
        }
        .environment(\.tabBarVisibility, $tabBarVisible)
    }
}

struct CustomTabBar: View {
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int
    @Binding var tabbarVisible: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            TabBarButton(imageName: "house", isSelected: selectedTab == 0, action: { selectedTab = 0 })
            TabBarButton(imageName: "magnifyingglass", isSelected: selectedTab == 1, action: { selectedTab = 1 })
            TabBarButton(imageName: "bell", isSelected: selectedTab == 2, action: { selectedTab = 2 })
            TabBarButton(imageName: "person", isSelected: selectedTab == 3, action: { selectedTab = 3 })
        }
        .padding(8)
        .background(
            Color.white
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 8, x: 0, y: -4)
        )
        .cornerRadius(25)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

struct TabBarButton: View {
    let imageName: String
    let isSelected: Bool
    let action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            Image(systemName: imageName)
                .font(.system(size: 24))
                .foregroundColor(isSelected ? .white : .black.opacity(0.65))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .background(isSelected ? Color.purple.opacity(0.7) : Color.clear)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
        }
    }
}

// Environment key for tab bar visibility
struct TabBarVisibilityKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Binding<Bool> = .constant(true)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var tabBarVisibility: Binding<Bool> {
        get { self[TabBarVisibilityKey.self] }
        set { self[TabBarVisibilityKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

How I Use It
In ContentView:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainTabView()
    }
}

In Other Views (example of hiding/showing TabBar):
struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.tabBarVisibility) var tabBarVisibility
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                // Content here
                Button("Toggle TabBar") {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                        tabBarVisibility.wrappedValue.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Hide tab bar when view appears
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                tabBarVisibility.wrappedValue = false
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            // Show tab bar when view disappears
            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                tabBarVisibility.wrappedValue = true
            }
        }
    }
}

Desired Behavior

When TabBar is visible:

Works normally with all buttons clickable
Animates smoothly when hiding/showing
White background with shadow


When TabBar is hidden:

Area where TabBar would be should not respond to taps
Other UI elements in that area should still be interactive
No visual elements should be visible



Environment

iOS 15+
SwiftUI
Xcode 14

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this? I specifically need to prevent interactions with the TabBar area when it's hidden while allowing other UI elements to still be interactive.
What I've Tried

Using a clear Rectangle to block interactions:

if !tabBarVisible {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.clear)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .contentShape(Rectangle())
        .onTapGesture { }
}

Problem: This blocks ALL interactions in that area, including legitimate UI elements.

Using allowsHitTesting:

if !tabBarVisible {
    CustomTabBar(selectedTab: $selectedTab, tabbarVisible: $tabBarVisible)
        .opacity(0)
        .allowsHitTesting(false)
}

Problem: This doesn't block any interactions at all.

Using an invisible placeholder:

if !tabBarVisible {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        // Same buttons as CustomTabBar but with empty actions
    }
    .opacity(0)
}

Problem: Still allows interactions to pass through.


Doesn't your current code already do that? Can you show a [mcve] that includes something interactable in the tab bar area, and describe how you want it to behave, and how it currently behaves?

added to the question content

I think the reason why you can change tabs even when your custom tab bar is hidden is because the native tab bar is still present. You don't see it because there are no TabItem associated with your views, but empty buttons with no labels are still present and these are receptive to taps.
To confirm the issue, try adding some TabItem:
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
    HomeView()
        .tabItem { Text("Home") }
        .tag(0)
    FavoritesView()
        .tabItem { Text("Favourites") }
        .tag(1)
    // ...
}

You could also try turning on button shapes in the accessibility settings. This will make the tappable areas visible where the empty buttons are present.
The problem can be resolved by hiding the native tab bar. To do this, add .toolbarVisibility(.hidden, for: .tabBar) to each child view (and remove the TabItem added above):
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
    HomeView()
        .toolbarVisibility(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        .tag(0)
    FavoritesView()
        .toolbarVisibility(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
        .tag(1)
    // ...
}

